# XCode shows old warnings

Tags: xcode, svn, warnings

I have an xcode project with restkit integration. In Restkit usage there was some deprecated functions calls - and xcode showed bunch of warnings like:
Thiss API... is depreceted

So I changed them to newer ones and all warnings dissapear. However after today's update from svn I have all old warnings come back, but there are no old code lines. Xcode points on unexisting errors.

I've tried to clean the project etc, nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reverting back the .xcodeproj file. Actually what might have happened is, person who had these warning must have committed all the project settings also. Since you took an update, you got those settings back. So first revert the .xcodeproj file from svn. Then commit with new settings